# How do I get values from a struct in a different cpp file?

Tags: c++, struct

I think there are many solutions outside for my problem but I dont get it, I'm kind of new to structs - so please help me..

OK my problem is I declare a struct in my header.h file and there is a function also inside that puts a string in one of the struct values and in the header file I can also output the string, but I want that struct and that !!value!! in a different cpp file where I can access to that value - so here is my code

header.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

struct FUNCTIONS
{
  std::string f_name;
};
//extern FUNCTIONS globalStruct;

//put in struct variable
void put2struct()
{
  struct FUNCTIONS struct1;
  struct1.f_name = "FUNCTION";
  std::cout << "Functionname: " << struct1.f_name << std::endl;

}

#endif //FUNCTIONS_H
```

and main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#include "header.h"

using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  struct FUNCTIONS globalStruct;
  put2struct();

  //FUNCTIONS struct1;
  std::cout << "Functionname2: " << globalStruct.f_name << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I hope somebody can help me I really dont get it how to do this :/

Comment: Why does the function hard-code a local struct instead of taking an argument? What's the point of that?

Comment: You could make the struct static in the function and return it by reference.

Comment: That has nothing to do with structs and files. You need a C++ book, specifically the part about return values and scope.

Comment: I just want to see how it goes for one attribute of an struct - there are more attributes incoming for the struct - so please just show me the way for getting the "string" which I put into the f_name attribute to output in the main file

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to directly access a local variable outside the block where it is defined. Because `struct1` is an automatic variable, it is destroyed when `put2struct` returns, and no longer exists after that.

You can write a function that takes a `FUNCTIONS` by reference, and modify `put2struct` to call that function. That way you can access `struct1` from a different cpp file:

```
void foo(FUNCTIONS&);

void put2struct()
{
    FUNCTIONS struct1;
    // do your thing
    foo(struct1);
}

// another file
void foo(FUNCTIONS& object) {
    // you have access to the object passed by reference
}
```